# Find size of a window

Tags: resolution

When I have a window for an application open I would like its size, height and width. Is it 900 * 625, 716 * 456 or what?

The reason I need to know is just for some usability testing.

Any tips how I get this info?

Comment: In what format do you need it ?, from GUI or from terminal?

Answer (score 3):

If you want it in a UI use `Accessibility Inspector`. It's in `Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Accessibility Inspector` (It requires to install Xcode).

Answer (score 2):

You could also run something like these scripts in AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTunes"
     size of window 1
end tell
```

```
tell application "iTunes" to set b to bounds of window 1
{(item 3 of b) - (item 1 of b), (item 4 of b) - (item 2 of b)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [xScope](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xscope/id447661441?mt=12) for my usability and design needs. It's a paid product, and it does much, much more than simply measuring windows. However, the tools for adding rulers to the screen and measuring windows are highly evolved and packed with many features if you do this measurement regularly.